# Getting error while trying to match two array using PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I am getting the following error while comparing two array using PHP.

**Error:**

> **Notice: Undefined offset:** 1 in /opt/lampp/htdocs/test/search.php on line 7
>
> **Notice: Undefined offset:** 1 in /opt/lampp/htdocs/test/search.php on line 15
>   
> delete the value
>
> **Notice: Undefined offset:** 2 in /opt/lampp/htdocs/test/search.php on line 7
>
> **Notice: Undefined offset:** 2 in /opt/lampp/htdocs/test/search.php on line 15
>   
> delete the value

I am explaining my code below.

```
$maindata=array(array('id'=>3),array('id'=>7),array('id'=>9));
 $childata=array(array('id'=>3),array('id'=>45));
for($i=0;$i<count($maindata);$i++){
      //print_r($childata);
       if(count($childata) > 0){
           if(in_array($childata[$i],$maindata)){
               echo "get the value \n".$maindata[$i]['id'];
               echo "insert the value \n".$maindata[$i]['id'];
               unset($childata[$i]);
               if(count($childata) > 0){
                   $childata=array_values($childata);
               }
           }else{
               echo "delete the value \n".$childata[$i]['id'];
               unset($childata[$i]);
               if(count($childata) > 0){
                   $childata=array_values($childata);
               }
           }
       }else{
           echo "get the value \n".$maindata[$i]['id'];
           echo "insert the value \n".$maindata[$i]['id'];
       }
    }
```

Please help me to resolve this error.

Comment: What you want to check from the condition....

Comment: @PHPGeek : Here i need to check if `$childata` value is present inside `$maindata` array then the two `echo` will execute and that particular value will remove.Once `$childata` length will be zero then the 2nd else part will excute.

Comment: Then I think you need a single dimensional array instead of 2-D  array.. Is there any need of this array...

Comment: @PHPGeek : Can you make this correct ?

Comment: why don't you use `array_udiff_assoc` with a callback or something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> It's somewhat unclear why you are doing exactly the same thing in both the `if` and `else` Clauses within Your Loop. However; below is a Snippet that might possibly give you a little idea on how to *perhaps revisit your approach*. [Quick-Test Here](https://eval.in/677744):

```
<?php

    $mainData   = array( array('id'=>3), array('id'=>7), array('id'=>9) );
    $childData  = array( array('id'=>3), array('id'=>45) );

    foreach($mainData as $iKey=>$subArray){
        echo "get the value \n"     . $mainData[$iKey]['id']  . "<br />";
        echo "insert the value \n"  . $mainData[$iKey]['id']  . "<br />";
        // CHECK TO SEE THAT THE ARRAY $childData IS NOT EMPTY
        if(!empty($childData)){
            // THEN LOOP THROUGH THE $childData ARRAY
            // AND IF YOU SIMILAR ELEMENT IS FOUND TO  EXIST IN $mainData
            // DELETE (UNSET) ITS EQUIVALENT IN THE $childData
            foreach($childData as $iKey2=>$subArray2){
                if(in_array($subArray2, $mainData)){
                    unset($childData[$iKey2]);
                }else{
                    // YOU ARE DOING EXACTLY THE SAME THING YOU DID IN THE IF CLAUSE
                    // HERE AGAIN IN THE ELSE CLAUSE: IS THAT WHAT YOU REALLY WANT?
                    // THAT IS YOU ARE REPEATING: "unset($childData[$iKey2]);" ???
                    echo "delete the value \n"  . $childData[$iKey2]['id'] . "<br />";
                    unset($childData[$iKey2]);

                    // MOST LIKELY; YOU DON'T NEED THIS ELSE CLAUSE AT ALL
                    // unset($childData[$iKey2]);
                }
            }
            // GET THE ARRAY VALUES IF THE $childData is NOT EMPTY
            $childData  = (!empty($childData))? array_values($childData):$childData;
        }
    }
```

Comment: @Pioz : Let me to clear my requirement.For any common value between two array the two `echo` statement will execute and for the remaining value the single `echo` statement will execute.

Comment: @subhra  Check the Code again.... https://eval.in/677729   and by the way, the name is **Poiz** not ***Pioz*** **;-)**

Comment: Sorry first. Ok its not working as per expected. Let me to explain again.Here for the all value from first array (`$mainData`) the two `echo` must execute . If any common value is there in second array (`here 3`) that will be ignored. apart from that any remaining value is in second array ('i,e-$childData') for this single `echo` will execute.

Comment: Here output should be like coming from begining (`get the value 3
insert the value 3
delete the value 45
get the value 7
insert the value 7
get the value 9
insert the value 9`).Suppose `$childData  = array( array('id'=>34), array('id'=>45) );` in this case its not working.

Comment: @subhra  **LOL :-)**  Post updated...try it again... https://eval.in/677744

Comment: @subhra   Please, do not just accept answers.... ***Try always to double-check before you endorse...*** in your case; try to change and switch the values of `$childData`. If after thorough checking, everything still meets the expected result(s) consistently, you may then confidently endorse/accept an answer. **;-)** This is helpful to both yourself and especially the Solution-Contributor... and lets him see as work upon his weak-points.